# Need help implementing a remove() method for my linked-list class

Tags: python, data-structures, linked-list

I'm currently learning data structures in Python, I'm trying to create a linked lists. I got the `append` and `get_size` and `display` methods working, but when I try to create a `remove` method. It removes the particular element, but when I try to print all the elements using the `display` method again, it's printing an empty list.

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, data=None):
        self.data = data
        self.ref = None
        
class Linked:
    def __init__(self):
        self.head = Node() 
        self.size = 0 

    def append(self, data): 
        new = Node(data)   
        cur = self.head 
        while cur.ref != None:
            cur = cur.ref
        cur.ref = new
        self.size += 1
    
    def get_size(self):
        return self.size

    def display(self): 
        el = []
        cur_node = self.head
        while cur_node.ref !=None: 
            cur_node = cur_node.ref
            el.append(cur_node.data)
        return el
    
    def remove(self, data):
        this_node = self.head
        prv_node = None
        while this_node != None:
            if data == this_node.data:
                if prv_node:
                    prv_node.ref = this_node.ref
                else:
                    self.head = this_node.ref
                    
                self.size -= 1
                return F"The item is removed "
            else:
                prev_node = this_node
                this_node = this_node.ref
        return F"data not found"
```

Comment: Can you provide some client code which doesn't output the result you are looking for, and for which you know what the result needs to be?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to a full [mcve]. In specific, that means including the (minimal) code to demonstrate the issue – i.e. constructing a linked list, removing a node and displaying the result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The purpose of having `head` always refer to a node is to avoid needing special cases for operations like `remove`. `prev` and `cur` can be initialized to the head, with `cur` being set to the node following `prev` at the top of the loop. `prev` is updated at the bottom of the loop.

```
def remove(self, data):
    previous = self.head
    while prev.ref is not None:
        cur = prev.ref
        if cur.data == data:
            prev.ref = cur.ref  # Cut out cur
            self.size -= 1
            return "The item is removed"
        prev = cur
    return "data not found"
```

In Python 3.8, you can move the assignment to `cur` into the loop condition using the `:=` operator:

```
while (cur := prev.ref) is not None:
    if cur.data == data:
    ...
```

Also, I would encourage you not to return special strings to indicate success or failure. Some other options:

1. Return `True` if the item is removed, `False` otherwise
2. Return the node being removed, or `None` otherwise
3. Always return `None`
4. Always return `None`, but raise an exception if the item you wanted to delete wasn't found.